# Upstart shows non-existent process running

Tags: nginx, upstart, pid

I am using upstart 1.8-0ubuntu1 on Ubuntu-1210-quantal-64-minimal.

It shows me nginx to be running, when it's not.

```
# service nginx status
nginx start/running, process 2543
# ps -p 2543
PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

My config:

```
# nginx

description "nginx http daemon"
author "George Shammas <georgyo@gmail.com>"

start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=lo)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

env DAEMON=/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
env PID=/opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid

expect fork
#respawn
#respawn limit 10 5
#oom never

pre-start script
        $DAEMON -t
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
                then exit $?
        fi
end script

exec $DAEMON
```

Comment: probably somehow .pid file is somewhere didn't get deleted.

Comment: right so check if /opt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid exists and then compare it with "ps -waux | grep -i ngnix"